# Counting language frequencies in a pandas data frame using langdetect

Tags: python, pandas, frequency

I want to find the frequency of different languages in a tweet dataset. I eventually only want to use the tweets that are in English but want to find out the frequencies of other languages as well.

I've detected the language of tweets within my dataset using langdetect, and now I want to count the frequency of each language. This is my code for detecting the language:

```
from langdetect import detect    
import pandas as pd
data_path = "./output_1.csv"
df =  pd.read_csv(data_path, index_col=0)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(detect(row['text']))
    if detect(row['text']) == "en":
        print(row['text'])
```

I wanted to use list property count to count the frequencies:

```
using the list i = ['en','fr','es','it','cs','pt']
d = {x:i.count(x) for x in i}
print d
```

How do I use the count property on the data that I got using langdetect?

Comment: You have a column named `text` whose values are the language? In that case probably [`pd.Series.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html)

Comment: @ALollz I'm struggling to create a separate column which would contain just the output of the language detection. I tried

   `df["language"] = (detect(row['text']))`

But that just uses the first row and not each of them separately. Do you have any suggestions how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

To create a separate column containing the language you could do:

```
df['language'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: detect(x))
```

Then to count the frequency you could do:

```
pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('language').text.count().sort_values(ascending=False))
```